# Mapping sql alchemy database models defined in a separate file

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a website using flask (python). I would like to create my SQLAlchemy database models in a separate file and import them. I have tried the following code but getting import error. I have tried solutions from similar questions but none is working. What modifications are needed to be made in my code?

**structure**

[image]

**main.py**

```
from Website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

****init.py** (underscore not displayed)**

```
from flask import Flask
from .routes import routes
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from .dbmodels import Subscribers

DB_NAME = "myDatabase.db"
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    #..........................Register blueprint.......................#
    app.register_blueprint(routes, url_prefix='/')    
    
    #..........................Database config.......................#
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'        
    db.init_app(app)
    db.create_all()
    sub_1 = Subscribers(name="pavan")
    db.session.add(sub_1)
    db.session.commit()
      
    return app
```

**dbmodels.py**

```
from . import db
from datetime import datetime

class Subscribers(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.name
```

Comment: You probably want to declare `db` in `dbmodels` and import it from there in `__init__`.  Then you should be able to avoid the circular import problems.

Answer (score 0):

You import `Subscribers` from `dbModels` in `__init__` and `db` from `__init__` in `dbModelds`. It leads to circular imports.
The simpliest solution - put `db = SQLAlchemy()` in separate file (e.g. `extensions.py` and import it from this file in `__init__` and in `dbModels`